# Redirect .html links to .php links inside a folder using rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I have a folder called **'work'** on my server that previously had **.html** files in it. Now all the files have **.php** extensions but clients still have the old links to the .html files. I **don't** want to redirect all .html files to .php versions from the root of the server, I only want this rule applied inside the 'work' folder.

From the root I would use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

which worked fine. The problem is I now have the following rule applied for the root (used by wordpress for permalinks)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

so it has broken any individual redirects I had set up. Previously I had set up each one individually using:

```
RewriteRule /work/index\.html /work/index\.php [RP]
```

So I would like to know if there is a way I could redirect all .html links inside the 'work' folder to .php versions using a one-for-all rule. Failing that, how would I set up the redirects individually?

EDIT: I'm using ISAPI rewrite on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(work)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2.php [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: As a side-note if you don't mind, how would I go about excluding a sub-folder (/work/digital/archive/) from this rule?

Comment: Just put this condition above my RewriteRule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/work/digital/archive/ [NC]`